# How can i reflect/copy changes from one form to another in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Main Form named "GSAPAccounts" referred to a query with the same name and another form (not a subform) named "Failures" referred to query also named as failures.

I have a condition in my GSAPAccounts where, when a condition is met, Failures (form) will pop out. In my Failure forms I have 2 fields to be populated "General Reason" and "Comments" (which is also in my GSAPAccounts Form) and a command button to close the form, and I also have included the "ID" as the common field between the 2 forms.

My question now is: Is it possible that when I make changes in my "Failures" form to reflect it in my "GSAP Accounts" form?

I am quite new to MS Access, and what I've done so far is just the code below. When I make changes in the Failures form, it is not updating in my other form.
I already tried everything that I can find in Google but nothing is working for me.

```vb
If IsNull(Me.General_Reason) Or IsNull(Me.Comments) Then
    MsgBox "Provide M15 Failure Reason"   
Else
    DoCmd.Save
    DoCmd.Close               
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *refresh* or *requery* the other form in the *AfterUpdate* event of form "GSAP Accounts":

```
Forms!Failures.Refresh  
'or:
' Forms!Failures.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav.. It's working now and just to make sure, i also added a Dlookup as my default value in my 2 fields